# SPARQL QUERY duplicate result for 1 value and the result don't follow that i want (Final Year Project)

Tags: sql, sparql, ontology

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>     
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>   
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>    
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>   
PREFIX wo: <http://www.semanticweb.org/asus/ontologies/2022/11/weldingprocess#>    
SELECT DISTINCT ?weldingcurrent ?weldingvoltage ?gasflowrate ?tensilestrength   
WHERE {?processparameter rdfs:subClassOf wo:Process_Parameter.
?a rdf:type wo:Welding_Current.
?a wo:has_text_value ?weldingcurrent.
?b rdf:type wo:Welding_Voltage.
?b wo:has_text_value ?weldingvoltage.
?c rdf:type wo:Gas_Flow_Rate.
?c wo:has_text_value ?gasflowrate.
?d rdf:type wo:Tensile_Strength.
?d wo:has_text_value ?tensilestrength}ORDER BY ?weldingvoltage ?gasflowrate ?tensilestrength
```

[Result that come out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aBW0.jpg)
This is result that out from the SPARQL QUERY. I only want:

1.130A,23V, 13L/min, 268.28N/mm

2.130A, 25V, 15L/min, 289.82N/mm

3.130A, 27V, 17L/min, 327.20N/mm

The value that come out from the SPARQL QUERY also don't follow as i want.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for. Each row is different, so what do you expect as output from the first 3 lines which obviously differ in the last column? Which value do you expect and then why to choose that value for `?tensilestrength` - SPARQL can't do magic, you have to tell what to do

Answer (score 0):

The query is

```
  1 PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
  2 PREFIX  wo:   <http://www.semanticweb.org/asus/ontologies/2022/11/weldingprocess#>
  3 PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
  4 PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  5 PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
  6 
  7 SELECT DISTINCT  ?weldingcurrent ?weldingvoltage ?gasflowrate ?tensilestrength
  8 WHERE
  9   { ?processparameter
 10               rdfs:subClassOf    wo:Process_Parameter .
 11     ?a        rdf:type           wo:Welding_Current ;
 12               wo:has_text_value  ?weldingcurrent .
 13     ?b        rdf:type           wo:Welding_Voltage ;
 14               wo:has_text_value  ?weldingvoltage .
 15     ?c        rdf:type           wo:Gas_Flow_Rate ;
 16               wo:has_text_value  ?gasflowrate .
 17     ?d        rdf:type           wo:Tensile_Strength ;
 18               wo:has_text_value  ?tensilestrength
 19   }
 20 ORDER BY ?weldingvoltage ?gasflowrate ?tensilestrength
```

Nothing connects "?a ?weldingcurrent" (lines 11 and 12) to "?b ?weldingvoltage" (lines 13 and 14)/. Ditto ?c and ?d.

So you get each of the results from lines 11 and 12 tries with everything from lines 13 and 14 (it's a cross product).

Find something that relates ?a ?b ?c and ?d to ?processparameter.